Convert Rigged mesh to single mesh object
does anyone know if it's possible to convert a rigged mesh of a figure into a single mesh object in a particular pose?
I'd like to create a statue of a Mixamo figure, without the bones and in a particular pose (not with its arms out).
Thanks in advance

Yes you can. I don't have time to create an answer at the moment, but move along the timeline until you get the pose you want then apply the Armature modifier. You'll then need to unparent the mesh by selecting it and hitting Alt-H. That will put the model on its back so set the X rotation back from 90 to 0 degrees. Apply the transforms with Ctrl-A and you can then delete the armature.

Many thanks,John, trying to find an answer on Google seem to give many elaborate and non-related answers that concluded that it couldn't be done, but your method worked fine.
